# Trigger Dokku Deployment by GitHub commit to master

Tags: github, heroku, deployment, dokku

I've used Heroku a lot, and I really like it's GitHub integration: when I commit/merge PR to master branch, the PaaS triggers the new deployment. Right now I fell in love with Dokku and I want to reproduce the same behavior there.

I've tried to find the out-of-the-box solution for this or external plugin - but failed. I've also found the GitHub Action but it also [fails](https://github.com/idoberko2/dokku-deploy-github-action/issues/1).

How can I set up the GitHub repo integration to trigger new Dokku deployments?